# Unable to show "check" icon on click in Filterchip widget flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have built this custom widget based on Filterchip standard widget. The functionality is pretty much what you should expect on this widgets. It displays a list of attributes to filter a list. The problem comes when I click on one of these chips: they do not show the "check" button so that you know you have clicked it.

I followed this tutorial too:
https://www.woolha.com/tutorials/flutter-using-filterchip-widget-examples

```
  onSuggestionSearch(String textControllerValue) {
    List attributes = ['title', 'Breed', 'CityName'];
    List<bool> _selected = [false, false, false];
    List attributesFound = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < snapList.length; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < attributes.length; j++) {
        if (snapList[i][attributes[j]]
            .toLowerCase()
            .contains(textControllerValue.toLowerCase())) {
          attributesFound.add(attributes[j]);
        }
      }
    }
    List attributesFoundDistinct = attributesFound.toSet().toList();
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Wrap(
            children: <Widget>[
              for (var i = 0; i < attributesFoundDistinct.length; i++)
                FilterChipCustom(
                    chipSelected: _selected[i],
                    color: Colors.red,
                    filtered: filteredByTag,
                    label: attributesFoundDistinct[i],
                    onSelected: (bool selected) {
                      setState(() {
                        attributesSelected = [];
                        _selected[i] = selected;
                        snapList = snapListAll;
                        _filteredDogList = snapList
                            .where((dog) => (dog[attributesFoundDistinct[i]]
                                .toLowerCase()
                                .contains(textControllerValue.toLowerCase())))
                            .toList();
                        filteredByTag = true;
                        attributesSelected.add(attributesFoundDistinct[i]);
                      });
                    }),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class FilterChipCustom extends StatelessWidget {
  var label;
  var color;
  var filtered;
  var chipSelected;
  final ValueChanged<bool> onSelected;

  FilterChipCustom(
      {Key? key,
      required this.label,
      this.color,
      required this.onSelected,
      this.chipSelected,
      this.filtered})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FilterChip(
      labelStyle: TextStyle(color: filtered == true ? Colors.red : Colors.blue),
      avatarBorder: Border.all(
        color: color,
        width: 1,
      ),
      labelPadding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
      avatar: CircleAvatar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade600,
        child: Text(label[0].toUpperCase()),
      ),
      label: Text(
        label,
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
      ),
      onSelected: onSelected,
      selected: chipSelected,
      backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
      selectedColor: color,
      elevation: 6.0,
      shadowColor: Colors.grey[60],
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
    );
    ;
  }
}
```

Comment: try putting `  List<bool> _selected = [false, false, false];
    List attributesFound = [];` outside the build method

Answer (score 0):

Use this flutter ChoiceChip :

Widget link: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ChoiceChip-class.html

Tutorial:
https://codesinsider.com/flutter-choicechip-example-tutorial/

Good luck !